# Solve $\sin(2\theta) -\tan(\theta) = 0 \ $ for $ 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I want to use the fact that $$\sin(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1 + \tan^2(\theta)}$$

to solve $\sin(2\theta) -tan(\theta) = 0  \ $ for $ 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

My solution:

$\frac{2tan(\theta)}{1 + tan^2(\theta)} - tan(\theta) = 0 $

so $\frac{2tan(\theta) - (1 + tan^2(\theta)) tan(\theta)}{1 + \tan^2(\theta)} = 0$

so $  2tan(\theta) - (1 + tan^2(\theta)) tan(\theta)= 0$

$ \implies \tan^3(\theta) + \tan(\theta) = 0$ $\implies \tan(\theta) [\tan^2(\theta) + 1] = 0$ $\implies \tan(\theta) = 0 \;\textrm{or}\; \tan^2(\theta) + 1 =0 $ since $\theta$ must be real.

Then we solve $\tan(\theta) = 0$ $\implies$ $\theta = n\pi, \ \ $ $ n \in Z \ \ $ so $\theta = \pi,2\pi$

Comment: OK. Go ahead.${}$

Comment: @MichaelT No, it's true, and it's quite usual: let $t=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$, then $\sin \theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos t =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: @MichaelT Your answer was good (with a minor sign mistake), and arguably more straightforward than the approach with tangents. Why delete it?

Comment: Your first **so** is of course wrong: you just introduced tangents to replace $\sin 2\theta$, but you write again the sine, instead of $2\tan \theta$. There is also a missing paren, but the line is wronge anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another way to solve:**

Since identity $\sin (2\theta)=\dfrac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$,  equation $\sin (2\theta)-\tan\theta=0$ is equivalent to 
\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{2}{1+\tan^2\theta}-1\right)\tan\theta&=0\;\;\;\text{ or}\\
\left(\dfrac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}\right)\tan\theta&=0\;\;\;\text{ or}\\
\frac{(1+\tan\theta)(1-\tan\theta)\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}&=0
\end{align}
It follows $\tan\theta=\pm 1$ or $\tan\theta=0$. Thus $\theta=0,\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi,\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4},2\pi$ are the solutions in $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a solution
$$ \sin(2x) = 2 \cos x \sin x = \tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \implies  \cos^2x = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$\therefore \cos x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \quad or \quad \sin x = 0 $$

Comment: right! Forgot about the $\pm$

Comment: Not a big mistake, and the answer is (I think) better than with tangents (faster, cleaner). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
\begin{align}
\sin2\theta&=\tan\theta\\
\frac{2\tan\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta}&=\tan\theta\\
\frac{2}{1 + \tan^2\theta}&=1\\
\tan^2\theta-1&=0\\
(\tan\theta-1)(\tan\theta+1)&=0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

tan squared theta  = 1 can actually be turned into a quadratic equation and solved then replace back when you are done. Sorry can not edit answered this in a rush.